# object creation in block

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Im trying to create view controller in my block call and when its returning from block my object becomes nil. How to fix it?

my block declaration:

```
typedef void (^GetViewController)(UIViewController *viewController, int index);
```

calling block when VC is needed (viewController is nil now)

```
self.getViewController(viewController, index);
```

setting VC in another class

```
self.myController.getViewController = ^(UIViewController *viewController, int index)
{
    switch (index) {
        case Option1:
            viewController = [[Option1VC alloc] init];
            break;
        case Option2:
            viewController = [[Option1VC alloc] init];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
//at this point VC is created
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointer to pointer is an option, ie

```
typedef void (^GetViewController)(UIViewController** viewController, int index);

...

self.myController.getViewController = ^(UIViewController** viewController, int index)
{
    *viewController = nil; // Avoid random value

    switch (index) {
        case Option1:
            *viewController = [[Option1VC alloc] init];
            break;
        case Option2:
            *viewController = [[Option1VC alloc] init];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
//at this point VC is created
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Your block is modifying a parameter that is passed to it. Parameters are passed by value, so the changed value is discarded.

Why not make the block return a view controller as the block result? That way the compiler should generate code so that it stays alive until the caller has a chance to assign the result to a strong variable.

Comment: I've changed it to return VC and it worked fine, but then I realised how apple is doing it. I made dataSource delegate and now its much more reusable

Answer (score 0):

You can use the __block storage type modifier on variables to modify them in a block.  Without this modifier, variables are read-only in the scope of the block.  This should get you around passing the parameter by value.

[Apple's __block variables documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW5)